# How can I convert a video to h264, using pass-through if available?

Tags: windows, video, video-conversion, mp4, h.264

On my Windows 7 computer, I have several videos that need converting to an iOS-friendly format. I'd like to do this as efficiently as possible.

I have several kinds of videos:

- MKVs containing (h|x)264 video and mp3 or AAC2ch.
- AVI files containing any arbitrary video or audio stream.

I want to convert them to MP4s with h264 video with AAC2ch audio. On the Mac, I use [MP4Tools](http://www.emmgunn.com/mp4tools/mp4toolsdownload.html) and it does a great job. I can't find anything similar on Windows.

Is there an ffmpeg command, or an application that I can use that will simply pass-through the video when it's in the correct format? All of the Windows conversion software I have used just re-encodes the video, which adds a lot time, and reduces quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the video and audio is already encoded properly, use the following FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy output.mp4
```

This will copy the bitstreams without encoding.

To convert AVI files you usually want to re-encode them, since they will often contain MPEG-4 visual video and MP3 audio instead of the required (or recommended) h.264 / AAC.

Comment: Is there a one-size-fits-all command that will re-encode when necessary?

Comment: @Redandwhite Not really, because there are [some peculiarities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html) as to how the h.264 (and audio, I guess) codec(s) need to be created, e.g. with a [certain profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles), without B-pictures, and you'd need to check these before attempting to re-encode. You could probably set up a batch script that parses MediaInfo output and re-encodes if necessary though.

Comment: if your offering a complete solution, why not just use a ffmpeg based video player on the iphone devices, so much easier than conversion and better on server bandwidth